# Does it violate Open Closed Principle

Tags: c#, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

I have an exception handling code that i think that it violates Open/Closed Principle. Because of these exceptions derived from system.exception i can not find a way for applying Open closed principle like the classical Shape example (http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-simple-example-of-the-openclosed-principle/)

Could you please help me about refactoring this code block

```
        switch (exception)
        {
            case DuplicateNameException _:
                returnMessage = DefaultResponseMessages.RecordExistsError;
                break;
            case KeyNotFoundException _:
                returnMessage = DefaultResponseMessages.NotFoundError;
                break;
            case ArgumentException _:
                returnMessage = DefaultResponseMessages.ArgumentExceptionError;
                break;
            case AuthenticationException _:
                returnMessage = DefaultResponseMessages.LoginError;
                detailMessage = string.Empty;
                break;
            case UnauthorizedAccessException _:
                returnMessage = DefaultResponseMessages.UnauthorizedAccessError;
                detailMessage = string.Empty;
                break;
        }
```

And this is another method;

```
    public static HttpStatusCode ExceptionToStatusCode(this Exception exception)
    {
        switch (exception)
        {
            case KeyNotFoundException _:
                return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            case DuplicateNameException _:
                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            case ArgumentException _:
                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            case UnauthorizedAccessException _:
                return HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            default:
                return HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define `ToStatusCode` inside `CONCRETEException` object.

Comment: Check out strategy pattern

Comment: I noticed that you figured out your problem. What you can do it post the solution that worked for you as an answer so that others can benefit from it in the future. It would also earn you some point in the process.

Comment: So, @KemalFahri, what was the solution?